# how to display/append more records to scroll to bottom using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery. I have to implement a Facebook like functionality in my web app that when a user scrolls to the bottom, more records are brought and appended/displayed to the page. I have been able to successfully send the ajax request on scroll to bottom and fetch the records. The data I have brought from the server is perfect. But I am stuck in figuring out how to display/append that data to the page. I have tried something and failed. Please suggest.

My ajax call:

```
var noOfMessageLoadsDone = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
  if(!$.active){ 
    $.get(
    "/fetchMoreOnScroll",
    {loadsDone: noOfMessageLoadsDone},
    function(data) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var datum = data[i];
        var el = $("div .container").find("div .container").first().clone();
        el.removeAttr("id");
        el.attr("statusId", datum.id);
        if(datum.statuserPicName){
          el.children('img').attr("src", "/images/"+datum.statuserPicName);
        }

        el.find('p').text(datum.statuserFirstName+' '+datum.statuserLastName+': ');

        $("div .container").find("div .container").append(el);
      };

      noOfMessageLoadsDone++;
    }
   );
  }  
 }
 });
```

Also suggest if there is a more elegant solution to this problem than what I am trying to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have read the doc on [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for jQuery. And which in your case the append should happen to the end of ".container". However in your selector you seem to have a space between "div" and ".container" which states that ".container" needs to be a children of a "div" element for it to find it. Try using the selector "div.container".

Comment: I am changing the approach now. I am creating a sample `div` containing all the tags but empty. I will select this `div`, clone it, populate it and then append it at the end of `$(div.container)`.
Thanks for adding to my knowledge that space means children. :)